# Yesod's wrap needs transformers > 0.2.2 and < 0.4, it conflicts with local version

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-warp

I created a new yesod project as,

```
yesod init
cd lemonstand && cabal sandbox init && cabal install
```

Package dependency resolution fails as,

```
next goal: warp (dependency of lemonstand-0.0.0)
rejecting: warp-3.0.12.1, 3.0.12,,,,(conflict: lemonstand => warp>=1.3 && <1.4)
rejecting: warp-1.3.10.2, 1.3.10.1,,,,(conflict: transformers==0.4.3.0, warp => transformers>=0.2.2 && <0.4)
rejecting: warp-1.2.2, 1.2.1.1,,,,(conflict: lemonstand =>warp>=1.3 && <1.4)
Backjump limit reached (change with --max-backjumps)
```

On running `cabal exec ghc-pkg list transformers`, it shows,

```
/opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4/package.conf.d
   transformers-0.3.0.0
/home/user/ws/yesod/lemonstand/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.4-packages.conf.d
```

What does `conflict: transformers==0.4.3.0` mean in the error line? And since `warp` expects the `transformers` versioned > 0.2.2 and < 0.4, can i install `transformers` inside the sandbox folder?

Since transformers come as part of ghc's inbuilt libraries, i am not sure how to install a different version of `transformers`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've hit the limits of cabal's dependency solver backjumps. You can:

- Add the flags `--max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals`
- Follow the [quickstart guide](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) which uses Stackage to avoid this problem
- Use [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) instead of cabal, which fixes this and many other problems. Note that this workflow is [still being refined](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2015/06/stack-support-yesod-devel)